# How to save an `exr` from a pytorch tensor in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

Previously, there was a function `torchvision.utils.save_float_image` with which it was possible to store an `.exr` file from a pytorch tensor. This function is gone in the current relase (0.17). Now, there is only the function `torchvision.utils.save_image` (https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.utils.save_image.html#torchvision.utils.save_image). But when I try to execute

```
with open(os.path.join('folder/', `foo.exr`), "wb") as fout:
    save_image(tensor, fout)
```

I'm receiving the error "unknown file extension *.exr". So, what can we do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python Imaging Library doesn't support `exr` files, [ref](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html). The only function available for saving images in Torchvision is [`save_image`](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.utils.save_image.html), [it uses PIL](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/main/torchvision/utils.py#L150) to save the file. As far back as the first documented version ([`0.8`](https://pytorch.org/vision/0.8/search.html?q=save_float_image%20&check_keywords=yes&area=default)), there was never a "save_float_image" function.

What you may use instead is [`imageio`](https://github.com/imageio/imageio) (`pip install imageio`):
You can get a reference by looking at the [unit test](https://github.com/imageio/imageio/blob/085ce272ae33e9ee37da43d03bcca35bbb5d571d/tests/test_freeimage.py#L693-695) for saving an `exr` file. You can save to disk by first transposing and converting to numpy array:

```
arr = tensor.permute(1,2,0).numpy()
imageio.imwrite('out_path.exr', arr)
```

Where `out_path` has the `.exr` extension file, otherwise you must use the option: `extension=".exr"`

---

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
import os
os.environ["OPENCV_IO_ENABLE_OPENEXR"] = "1"

tensor = torch.rand(3,100,150)
arr = tensor.permute(1,2,0).numpy()
imageio.imwrite('out_path.exr', arr)
```

Comment: THank you for your answer. Why is the transposition necessary?

Comment: Just noticed that your code yields the error "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not ndarray". Seems like we cannot pass a numpy array?!

Comment: I'm actually not sure whether this error is a type error in the first or second arg. If it is in the second arg instead, maybe the reason is that my tensor is currently in the format `(channel_count, width, height)`, but I guess `imageio` expects a 2-dimensional array of rgb values. I've asked separately of how we obtain this here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78175324/547231.

Comment: I have edited my answer above, my mistake: it should be [`imwrite`](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/v2.14.0/reference/_core_29/imageio.imwrite.html) and not `save`, and the path should come first.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Have you tried it?